# Is there such an algebra structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a ring, it holds that 1)
$$a×1=a=1×a$$ and 2) $$a×0=0=0×a$$ 
, so naturally, this 3) also holds
$$0×1=0=1×0$$

Is there such an algebra structure *weaker* than a ring so that 
1) or 2)
does not hold, but 3) still holds?

Comment: Maybe they shouldn’t be called 0 and 1 without specifying their properties.

Comment: What does the symbol "$1$" refer to in such a structure if condition (1) doesn't hold?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. It's called a group. Say we have a group made out of four elements, called $0,1,2,3$, where each elements is a mapping of ${0,1,2,3}\to{-i,1,i,-1}$ (I did $e^{i\pi (n-1)/2}$), and where $\times$ is the regular complex multiplication. Then any number multiplied with "$1$" is that number, and any number multiplied with "$0$" means a multiplication by $i$. Then the second equation does not hold, but the third does, since  $1$ is the identity element.

Comment: In ring 0 is the identity element of addition while 1 is the one for multiplication

Comment: And what are those supposed to be in your new structure? If they have the same properties as the ring, then **you have a ring**, and equation 1 is in the definition of the multiplication, and equation 2 is derived from the properties of the ring. Equation 3 is always true if 1 is true.

Comment: if there’s some structure that has addition and multiplication but maybe not law of distribution?